# Why pass array as "int *& name"?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was given a (C++) code where arrays are passed using

```
void fun(int *& name){...}
```

but what is the idea behind that? I guess it means "an array of references" but when you just pass a pointer to the first element that would be fine, wouldn't it? So what is the motivation to do it this way?

Comment: It means reference of a pointer variable. The purpose is to change the pointer variable passed to it.

Comment: Arrays? It is not possible to pass actual array objects through such parameter. What you can pass is a *pointer* that points to some array element, but not the array itself. For example, you won't be able to directly pass an `int a[10]` array to this function.

Comment: It is important to know that **arrays are not pointers, and pointers are  not arrays**. See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c) for more on that.

Answer (score 5):

The function receives a reference to a pointer. This means that the function can not only modify the `int` that is pointed to by `name`, but also that changes to the pointer *itself* made within the function call will also be visible outside.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int* allocate()
{
    return new int();
}

void destroy(int*& ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int* foo = allocate();

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    destroy(foo);

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
0x82dc008
0
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that the function can modify the value of the pointer in the caller.

i.e.

```
myName* foo; /* ToDo - initialise foo in some way*/
fun(foo);
/* foo might now point to something else*/
```

I regard this as an anti-pattern. The reason being that people reading your code will not *expect* `foo` to be modified in such a way since the calling syntax is indistinguishable from the more normal function `void anotherFun(int * name){...}`.

The stability of such code can suffer. As such, I'd recommend your using `void fun(int ** name){...}`. The calling syntax then becomes `fun(&foo)` which indicates to the function user that `foo` might be modified.

Comment: I would say it is an anti-pattern to use a pointer when you can use a reference. But I would do something different too: `int* fun(int* name);`, and return the new value.

Comment: Well, I personally don't like the pointer to pointer syntax where it is not really needed. So it depends on personal preference. However, I agree that in general it might come unexpected to the caller that the pointer can be modified. An alternative to using `int**` as you propose is to have a clear and well documented API with well chosen names for the functions, e.g. `deleteAndSetNull(int*& ptr)` for a function that deletes a pointer and sets it to NULL.

Comment: It's funny how divisive this is: I obviously respect your opinion and like the proposal to use `int* fun(int* name)`. I dislike references used in the way the OP has as they make code hard to read and bugs can be introduced by juniors working on collaborative projects. At least use a `const &` if possible.

Comment: If you want to ensure that `foo` wouldn't be modified, you can use `fun(myName *const &name)`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Indeed and good advice indeed if taking a value copy is expensive. (In this case though taking a reference will be slower than passing by value unless the compiler optimises out the internal reference counts).